# Conversion from .ui to .py in python 3 on windows platform

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, python-3.6, pyuic

I am trying to convert .ui file generated from Qt designer to .py file using PyQt5 (pyuic5.bat)

It is throwing DLL missing error

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Tried pasting python3.dll, python36.dll, msvcp110.dll, msvcr110.dll from python36 folder to System32 and SysWOW64. But the issue stays...

Comment: How did you install PyQt on your System? Via `pip3`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error converting .ui file to .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551316/error-converting-ui-file-to-py-file)